# How can I access a children inside a json file

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array

```
                i=0
            for element in data["system"]:
                #print(element)

                for index_in, nested_node in enumerate(data["system"][i]["children"]):
                    print(data["system"][i]["children"][index_in]["name"])
                    print(str(item.text(0)))
                    print(nested_node['name'])

                    if nested_node["name"] == str(item.text(0)):
                        print("Done")
                        del nested_node["system"][i]["children"][index_in]["name"]
                        #del element[index_in]

            i = i + 1
```

```js
JSON:
"system": [
        {
            "title": "AirConditioning",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Samsung"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daikin"
                },
```

```js
for element in data["system"]:
                #print(element)
                
                for index_in, nested_node in enumerate(data["system"][i-1]):
                    print(data["system"][i-1]["children"][index_in])
                    if nested_node["system"][i-1]["children"][index_in] == str(item.text(0)):
                        del data["system"][i-1]["children"][index_in]
                        #del element[index_in]
                    
                i = i + 1
            print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
            with open("systems_list.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)
```

I am trying to access a children inside a json file and delete based on an if statement but it seems that my program never enters the if statement

Comment: Can you show what you have written and your json file?

Comment: Hard to imagine how your json file and if statement and whole code structure look like. Please write them in questions.

Comment: Still cannot view your json file. One thing to notice. donot delete your data while you are iterating through it.

Comment: Ignore the [i-1] it is a mistake it should be [i]

Comment: What is your initial i value? Did you set it to 0?

Comment: Yes i=0 is the initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to access children is quite straightforward.

```
data["system"][index_1]["children"][index_2]["name"] will bring you there.
```

But so far from your code,

```
nested_node["children"][index_in]['name']
```

brings you a dict, which is, for example

```
{
     "name": "Samsung"
}
```

But you are comparing it to a string:

```
str(item.text(0))
```

`Dict==Str` is always False. So the code never goes into your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think using i in here is a bit redundant because you're using a for loop anyway.

Why not do:

```
#open file
with open("systems_list.json", "r", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
            nested_json json.load(json_file)

# let's assume this is what it looks like inside nested_json: 
{"parent1" : 
    {"child 1": "sample1", "child 2": "sample2"} 
{"parent2" :
    {"child 1": "sample1", "child 2": "sample2"} 
}

for element in nested_json:
    if element["child 1"] == sample1:
        element.pop('hours', None) #this will erase the child based on value
```

for element in data:
    element.pop('hours', None)

with open("systems_list.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as data_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4) #save new file